# How to parse an object and match its key/values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I am just working with an object that comes back a little bit strange from an API.

Here is the object in question

```
const body = {"body": "\"EVENT_TYPE\",\"TIMESTAMP\",\"REQUEST_ID\"\n,"Login\",\"20210907210944.873\",\"abc123\"\n}
```

The idea here is take this object, and it's return would be...

```
{
  body:{
 EVENT_TYPE: "Login",
 TIMESTAMP: "20210907210944.873",
 REQUEST_ID: "abc123"   
 }
}
```

I have been trying things like JSON.parse or JSON.stringify, but I have a feeling a loop might be necessary here or regex. Please feel free to drop some code examples if possible.

Comment: parse it as csv

Comment: The code is not valid and won't work any way you try to parse it. The reason is that some of the quotes are escaped (`\"EVENT_TYPE\"`), but there's not equal amount of escaped quotes. For example Login has a closing, but not an opening one (it starts with a regular `"` in front).